# Shift non-overlapping columns so that they overlap/align

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, aggregate-functions, pandas-groupby

I've got unevenly spaced timeseries that a resample to a slightly higher frequency (in this case `1min`) so that I can perform some calculations. Now there is one column, named `minor` in the example, which some times delayed by a few rows, some times it is correctly aligned. I need to find a way to align the end of the non-zero blocks in 'minor' with the ends of the non-zero blocks in `major`, as shown in the example:

```
major = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,4,4,4,4,4,5,6,7,0,0,0,0,4,3,5,6,4,0,0,0]
minor = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,.9,0]
# correctly aligned minor row:
minor_aligned = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,.9,0,0,0]
df = pd.DataFrame(
data={'major': major, 'minor': minor, 'minor_aligned': minor_aligned})
df.index.name = 'index'
```

**Expected Output:**
The values in `minor` should be aligned as in `minor_aligned`.

**Short explanation:**
The last non-zero value of each consecutive block of non-zero values in `minor` has to be aligned with the last non-zero value of each block in `major`, as shown with `minor_aligned`. The following additional restrictions apply:

- `minor` will be exactly 1 in 95% of the time (or 0), the rest will be a few values in between.
- `minor` can only be `> 0` where `major > 0`
- a non-zero block in `minor` can at most be as long as the corresponing block in `major`, but never longer. It will mostly be much shorter than the block in `major`
- If there is no corresponing block, `minor` must be `0`. (I haven't found such a case, thus this is optional)

**What I've tried so far:**
From [this post] I copied the `block`-counting method, furthermore I tried to implement some masking and experimented with all kinds of `cumcount`, `cumsum` etc., but I was not able to find a solution.

```
df['mask_mult'] = pd.DataFrame(  # mask where shifted rows exist
    np.where((df.minor != 0.) & (df.major == 0.), 1 * df.minor, 0),
    index=df.index, columns=['outliers'])
# block counting method:
df['block'] = (df.minor.shift(1) != df.minor).astype(int).cumsum()
df.loc[:, 'block'][df['minor'] == 0] = 0  # set zero-blocks to zero
```

Using groupby, categories and aggregate (no idea on how to put this to good use) I tried to put the masks/block to some use, but I was not succesful:

```
# make block counting categories:
df_cat = df.set_index(pd.cut(df.block, np.arange(-1, df.block.max() + 1)))
# groupby blocks and use mask as amount of shift indices:
df_grpd = df.groupby('block').sum()
```

I thought I could either iterate over all categories in `df_cat` to get the shift indices or iterate over the grouped blocks in `df_grpd` to do the same (and use the summed `mask` as number of rows to shift), but in both cases I don't get correct results due the `0.9`-value.

Any idea on how I could do this with values like `0.9` and if possible by avoiding loops completely?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution after understanding how `agg`/`aggregate` works. I was not able to completely avoid loops, but at least it is only looping over the aggregated blocks, while the rest is vectorized.
This solution should work for most kinds of inputs/types, as long as general shape and index requirements for concatenation along axis 1 are met.

```
def align_non_overlapping(ser_maj, ser_min, full_output=False):
    minor_colname = (  # backup name of minor if available
        ser_min.name if isinstance(ser_min, pd.Series)
        else ser_min.column if isinstance(ser_min, pd.DataFrame) else 'minor')
    # merge both series in df
    df = pd.DataFrame({'major': ser_maj, 'minor': ser_min})
    df_idx = df.index  # backup and drop index for easy general shifting
    df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
    # make mask where values are not overlapping
    df['mask_no'] = np.where((df.minor != 0.) & (df.major == 0.), 1, 0)
    # make mask where minor values are not zero
    df['mask_nz'] = (df.minor != 0).astype(int)
    # get blocks of consecutive non-zero values in minor
    df['block'] = (
        df['mask_nz'].shift(1) != df['mask_nz']).astype(int).cumsum()
    # set block to zero where minor is zero
    df.loc[df['minor'] == 0., 'block'] = 0
    # set block to zero where
    # generate shifting information. summing of mask_no gives amount of non
    # overlapping rows (n rows to shift), index min and max gives start and
    # end indices of blocks of non zero blocks. reset index to be able to apply
    # aggregate function on index
    shifter = df.reset_index().groupby('block').agg(
        {'mask_no': 'sum',
         'index': {'index_start': 'min', 'index_stop': 'max'}})
    # drop first level of MultiIndex for easier indexing
    shifter.columns = shifter.columns.droplevel(0)
    # loop over blocks and shift each block by aggregated values
    for blck in shifter.index:
        if shifter.loc[blck, 'sum'] == 0:  # skip all zero blocks/shifts
            continue
        n_shift, istart, iend = shifter.loc[blck]  # extract shifting bounds
        df.loc[istart - n_shift:iend, 'minor'] = np.roll(  # roll window
            df.loc[istart - n_shift:iend, 'minor'], -n_shift)
    df.set_index(df_idx, inplace=True)  # set backup index
    df.rename(columns={'minor': minor_colname}, inplace=True)  # set old name
    if not full_output:  # return full output with information only if required
        return df[minor_colname]
    else:
        return df
```

Test result against expected result:

```
ser_maj = pd.Series([0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,4,4,4,4,4,5,6,7,0,0,0,0,4,3,5,6,4,0,0,0], name='major')
ser_min = pd.Series([0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,.9,0], name='minor')
minor_aligned = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,.9,0,0,0]
print(align_non_overlapping(ser_maj, ser_min, full_output=False) == minor_aligned).all())
# Out: True
```

These conditions were currently ignored:

- minor can only be `> 0` where `major > 0`
- a non-zero block in minor can at most be as long as the corresponing block in major, but never longer. It will mostly be much shorter than the block in major

But both can easily be implemented with `df[df.major == 0] = 0`.